# Let a slack app create slash commands for another app? (Custom -> Jira)

Tags: slack, jira, bot

I am trying to automatically create a ticket every month in Jira. Jira has a slash command to create tickets, which I could use each month to create a ticket myself, but that would not be different than going to Jira and doing it myself.

I would like to have my custom slackbot send these slash commands on my behalf.

Problems so far:
I can't seem to get the bot to activate a slash command even if it types something with a slash in it.
Jira slash command opens a modal to get more information, so it's not just "/Jira create *detailsdetailsdetails*"

Any other solutions to recurring tickets for Jira that doesn't require a paid plugin are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a paid plan, you could try workflow steps for Jira. The official Jira Cloud app doesn't provide this functionality, but there are other apps that can let you add workflow steps.

Unfortunately, there is no way to execute slash commands related to other apps programmatically with Slack. You could possibly automate this using a selenium script, but then you run into the risk of breaking this integration as and when the Slack UI changes.